# hitting and batting in cricket and baseball

Tags: cricket, baseball, pitching, bowling

I was thinking, for a good international cricket batsman, or good MLB baseball batter:

1. How hard would it be for one to hit or bat in the other's sport,
   a) with the other sport's bat
   b) with his own sport's bat

Consider both fast and spin bowlers in cricket, and consider knuckleballers and normal (fast) pitchers in baseball.